# SELECT statement with multiple where conditions not running in .NET winform application

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a complex `SELECT` query that I run within a winform application. The query runs perfectly in `SQL Server`, but it times out/short circuits/something when I use the query in the application.

```
SELECT Q.ORDNUM FROM GISQC..QC_ORDERS AS Q 
INNER JOIN TOD..CURRENTORDERS AS NEW ON Q.ORDNUM = NEW.ORDNUM 
INNER JOIN GISQC..CLONEORDERS AS C ON C.NEWORDNUM = Q.ORDNUM 
INNER JOIN TOD..CURRENTORDERS AS OLD ON C.ORIGORDNUM = OLD.ORDNUM 
WHERE (Q.WEEK = '2015.17') AND (NEW.ORDSTAT = 'C') 
AND ((NEW.FLDZNE IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X') 
AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X')) 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X') 
AND OLD.FLDZNE IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X')) 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE LIKE 'A%' AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'A%') 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'A%' AND OLD.FLDZNE LIKE 'A%') 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE LIKE 'V%' AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LINE 'V%') 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'V%' AND OLD.FLDZNE LIKE 'V%') 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE') 
AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE')) 
OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE') 
AND OLD.FLDZNE IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE')))
```

I cannot create stored procedures in this application due to server restrictions, it has to be run dynamically. I have considered a `UNION ALL` but I'm unsure about syntax.

To clarify, my application crashes any time I call this query, I have debugged and know this is the issue.

**EDIT**

The completed code:

```
  Try
        Dim test As String = "SELECT Q.ORDNUM FROM GISQC..QC_ORDERS AS Q INNER JOIN TOD..CURRENTORDERS AS NEW ON Q.ORDNUM = NEW.ORDNUM INNER JOIN GISQC..CLONEORDERS AS C ON C.NEWORDNUM = Q.ORDNUM INNER JOIN TOD..CURRENTORDERS AS OLD ON C.ORIGORDNUM = OLD.ORDNUM WHERE (Q.WEEK = '2015.17') AND (NEW.ORDSTAT = 'C') AND ((NEW.FLDZNE IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X') AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X')) OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X') AND OLD.FLDZNE IN ('C', 'B', 'CX', 'BX', 'X')) OR (NEW.FLDZNE LIKE 'A%' AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'A%') OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'A%' AND OLD.FLDZNE LIKE 'A%') OR (NEW.FLDZNE LIKE 'V%' AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LINE 'V%') OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT LIKE 'V%' AND OLD.FLDZNE LIKE 'V%') OR (NEW.FLDZNE IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE') AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE')) OR (NEW.FLDZNE NOT IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE') AND OLD.FLDZNE IN ('D', 'NON', 'NONE')))"
        Dim datest As New SqlDataAdapter(test, Me.Qc_OrdersTableAdapter1.Connection)

        Dim dstest As New DataSet

        datest.Fill(dstest)

        Me.dgSFHA.DataSource = dstest.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The error message is: "Error: Incorrect syntax near 'LINE'."

There are no issues between the two databases. When I only include the first four conditions of the `WHERE` clause, it runs fine. I know it has to do with the complexity of this `WHERE` clause.

Comment: are you hitting the same database in both cases? what if you run a simpler query, just to try the connection and things like that?

Comment: `but it times out/short circuits/something when I use the query` ... `To clarify, my application crashes any time I call this query`  What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Please show how you are calling it from your application

Comment: you can check what user you are connecting as - the construct `TOD..CURRENTORDERS` has not specified the schema part, so it could referring to a different object if you are connecting to the database with different credentials in the application to those you use to manually test the statement

Comment: @gbianchi, see edits. The simpler query, with the 3 joins, runs fine using the connection string the code.

@mbeckish please see edits for error.

@BerndLinde complete code posted in edit.

@IanKenney nothing wrong with the schema, query runs fine with less `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Reread your string - "AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LINE 'V%'" :)

Comment: @Arvo holy moly, what a DUMB error. Please post this so I can mark it as answered. Not sure why I've been downvoted twice for this question...the rest of you are not very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(NEW.FLDZNE LIKE 'V%' AND OLD.FLDZNE NOT LINE 'V%')
```

That "NOT LINE" really should be a "NOT **LIKE**".